# Nav.Link not working in React bootstrap navbar (React-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am working on a project in React and trying to implement a bootstrap navbar and react-router-dom. I am able to get everything displaying properly, however, none of the links work.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-navbar-tmtwc) is a link to a codesandbox where I was able to replicate my issue

Any insights into what I am missing would be greatly appreciated!

```
<BrowserRouter>
<div className='page-container'>
  <div className='content-wrap'>
      <div>
        <>
          <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Container>
              <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Shake Up Fitness</Navbar.Brand>
              <Nav className="me-auto">
                <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/'>Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/activities'>Activities</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/signup'>Sign Up</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/contact'>Contact</Nav.Link>
              </Nav>
            </Container>
          </Navbar>
        </>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/activities" element={<Activities/>} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp/>} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<Footer />
</div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Are you sure of the versions of `react-bootstrap` being used? Your CSB is using v2 (v5 bootstrap) but you've tagged it with bootstrap v4. I tried several combinations of different versions of various packages. The `Container` component seems to be the issue. Adding the `fluid` prop or removing it entirely was the only way i could get the links to work. Basically the `Container` component is applying a full-screen overlay via an `::after` pseudo-element. I have no idea why it's doing that though.

Comment: After checking I am using v5, I accidentally tagged it wrong here, my bad there. Thank you for the explanation though, I appreciate it!

Comment: Seems that adding fluid inside my <container> tag also fixed the issue

Comment: Correct. I only didn't provide my comment as an answer as doing either appeared to also remove the padding or otherwise mess with the layout and I figured you were wanting/trying to maintain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<Container>` element wrapping the navbar. Seems like that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the arguments `activeStyle={{}}` from `react-router-dom` to the `<Nav.Link>`:

`<Nav.Link as={Link} activeStyle={{}} to='/'>Home</Nav.Link>`

This worked for me.

Comment: This helped me style the links as if I used <Link> from router-dom they looked like old skool hyperlinks... why is that?