# Nav Link not rerendering page when clicked. Force update freezes page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a nav bar for a website I'm building. The links in the nav bar to a section (#id) in the page but do not go to the section and only update the url. If I type in the url in the address bar, it works correctly but when using the link nothing happens.

It only works if I force the page to rerender, but after rerendering the page freezes and I get an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forceUpdate')`. I added an `onClick` and also tried using `setState` to force re-render.

Index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container fluid>
        <NavBar />
        <HomeContent />
      </Container>
      <Pricing />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

NavBar.jsx

```
function handleClick() {
  this.setState({ state: this.state });
  // this.forceUpdate();
}

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar variant="dark" expand="lg">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand onClick={handleClick} as={Link} to="/home">
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              <Nav.Link onClick={handleClick} as={Link} to="/home">
                Home
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link onClick={handleClick} as={Link} to="/home#pricing">
                Pricing
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Pricing.jsx

```
function Pricing() {
  return (
    <section id="pricing">
      <h2 className="section-heading">This is the pricing section</h2>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Pricing;
```

I also tried using `withRouter` on the `NavBar` component

I read that if I have to resort to forcing the page to render then I may be doing something wrong but I'm new to React and I've been searching for the past couple of days on better ways to do this but still couldn't find a better way to do it.

Comment: Open browser console and paste the errors here

Comment: I think this is your exact issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526223/1086398. The `react-bootstrap` API requires that the direct descendent of `Navbar` are only components in the `Navbar` namespace.

Comment: @adsy I would rather guess that `this` is `undefined`, because `handleClick` function is outside of the component and `NavBar` is not a class-component, but you can be right as well

Comment: Yeh I noticed that. I think he most likely just copied his example in bad or something but he wont need the `handleClick` anyway after this.

Comment: The links should just work and you shouldn't need to "force" React to rerender. I don't see any overt issues with the code you've shared here *other than* that it's not clear what the `this` is in the `handleClick` function, it seems undefined. Could you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nav-link-not-rerendering-page-when-clicked-force-update-freezes-page-d5i3fy) from your code and I am unable to reproduce any "app freezing" or need to force any rerender. You've only the the one `Home` component rendered on two routes, what exactly do you need to force here to see updates?

Comment: This is the code sandbox link: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-haze-zdwr18-zdwr18?file=/src/components/NavBar.jsx)

Comment: I'm trying to get the page to naviagte to the section with the id=pricing. The reason I added a handle click was because click on the link doesn't navigate the page to the section whereas typing the url in the address bar does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and [`this.forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) are older React class-based-only component methods. They won't work in React function components.

`react-router-dom` alone doesn't deal/handle with hash links, i.e. navigating to a specific route path ***and then*** scrolling to a specific hash anchor. Currently the [`react-router-hash-link`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) still works with `react-router-dom@6`. Import the `HashLink` from `react-router-hash-link` and use instead of the `Link` component from RRD.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink } from "react-router-hash-link"; // <-- import hash link

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/home"></Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home">
            Home
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={HashLink} to="/home#pricing"> // <-- hash link
            Pricing
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={HashLink} to="/home#about">   // <-- hash link
            About
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={HashLink} to="/home#contact"> // <-- hash link
            Contact
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

[image: Edit nav-link-not-rerendering-page-when-clicked-force-update-freezes-page]

Answer (score -1):

The best way to solve your problem to create React router structure in your web app. I suggest you to go through React router [beginners page](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial).

Also, in your case I suggest to create React router structure such as this structure:

You will have the main index.js file:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "mainpage/",
                element: <MainPage />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);
```

You will not have app.js file. You will just have a layout.jsx file:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from "./components/Nav";

const Layout = () => {
    return (<>
        <Nav />
        <Outlet />
    </>)
}
```

And you should just add paths and more children to index js. Just create some components and add them to children array as a main page one.

And in your nav component you must have links to your pages like in the following nav component example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Nav(props) {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <div className="header-container">
        <nav className="header-nav">
          <ul className="nav-list">
            <li>
              <Link to={`mainpage/`}>Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`News/`}>News</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`About/`}>About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`Contacts`}>Contacts</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

I hope you will solve your issue.